# Deleting a row when it remains one month in the database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

In my application, I want the user to be able to retrieve deleted information within one month.

For example:

```
Create Table 'Names' (name varchar(20) primary key)

Create Table 'DeletedNames'
(
     name varchar(20) primary key,
     insertingTime DateTime not null
)
```

When I delete a row from the `Names` table, it is inserted into the `DeletedNames` table.

For example:

Deleting name `Mohammed`, it will be inserted into `DeletedNames`:

```
| Mohammed |  | 2017-6-11 10:00 PM |
```

I want to delete this after one month 2017-7-11 10:00 PM (automatically)

I haven't tried anything. Maybe trigger would be a solution, but I'm beginner in triggers.

Thank you

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Thanks marc_s,  I'm using MySQL

Comment: "Maybe trigger would be a solution, but I'm beginner in triggers" words to live by... just read the documentation and you will know how easy are they

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a trigger. Just set up an agent job with the delete statement. Schedule it to run every day.

```
DELETE FROM DeletedNames WHERE InsertingTime < DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
```

In MySQL use the Event Scheduler.

Answer (score -1):

I'm also not that good with triggers, but have you tried making a trigger that will look a bit like:
    DELETE FROM deletedNames WHERE month > currentDate-30Days

Comment: May I suggest that you don't answer if you're not sure? You're new here, I won't downvote you, but your answer isn't formatted, isn't really an answer and the whole "bro" thing..